# Using Get-ChildItem to retrieve folder,name,fullname

Tags: powershell

I'm currently using this script to pull the Name,Folder,Foldername from a given path:

```
   Get-ChildItem "C:\user\desktop"  | Select Name, `
  @{ n = 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSParentPath } }, `
  @{ n = 'Foldername'; e = { ($_.PSPath -split '[\\]')[-2] } } ,
  @{ n = 'Fullname'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSParentPath } } |
    Export-Csv "C:\user\desktop\txt.txt" -Encoding Utf8 -NoTypeInformation
```

I am having trouble getting `@{ n = 'Fullname'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSParentPath } }` to pull through the full file path.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using expressions for properties that are there by default? The Name and FullName property already contain this info. Get-Childitem | Select-Object Name, Fullname should be enough.

Comment: @bluuf using Get-Childitem | Select-Object Name, Fullname would be fine but I wouldn't have the parent folder in a separate column. Only Name and FullName.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mistakenly referenced `PSParentPath` when you meant `PSPath` to get the full name (full filesystem path):

```bash
Get-ChildItem "C:\user\desktop" | Select Name, `
  @{ n = 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSParentPath } }, `
  @{ n = 'Foldername'; e = { ($_.PSPath -split '[\\]')[-2] } } ,
  @{ n = 'Fullname'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSPath } }  # NOT $_.PS*Parent*Path
```

However, as others have pointed out, the full path is a standard property on the output objects produced by `Get-ChildItem` (instances of type [`[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo)), so you can simply reference the **`FullName` property**:

```bash
Get-ChildItem "C:\user\desktop" | Select Name, `
  @{ n = 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSParentPath } }, `
  @{ n = 'Foldername'; e = { ($_.PSPath -split '[\\]')[-2] } } ,
  FullName
```

<sup>P.S.: `'\\'` will do as the RHS of the `-split` operator, but if you wanted to be cross-platform-friendly, you could use `[\\/]`</sup>

Note: The [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)-based technique used above (`@{ n = ...; e = ... }`, where `n` is short for `Name` and `e` for `Expression`) is called a *calculated property*, described in the conceptual [about_Calculated_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) help topic, across all cmdlets that support calculated properties.

Comment: For others, notice the use of the `@{ n = ... , e = { ... } }` technique described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.1#custom-expressions-in-common-pipeline-commands)

Comment: Thank you, @TheRedPea, good idea to link to an explanation. I've updated the answer with the link to the official help topic that now exists to describe this technique called _calculated properties_. The article you link to is helpful, but contains some editorializing that I find problematic ("I personally don't like how long that makes commands and it often promotes some bad behaviors that I won't get into.")

Answer (score 6):

[`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects (the output of `Get-ChildItem` for folders) have properties `Name` and `FullName` with the name and full path of the folder. They also have a property `Parent` that returns another `DirectoryInfo` object for the parent folder. You can add that information as a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

Since you basically want to add the grandparent name and path for the listed items, and that information doesn't change because you don't recurse, you can determine them once and add them as static information:

```
$dir = 'C:\some\folder'

$folder     = (Get-Item $dir).Parent
$folderName = $folder.Name
$folderPath = $folder.FullName

Get-ChildItem $dir |
    Select-Object Name, FullName,
        @{n='FolderName';e={$folderName}},
        @{n='Folder';e={$folderPath}} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -Encoding UTF8 -NoType
```

Comment: When I ran that only the name and fullname where populated. The rest the output was blank.

Comment: Then your folder contains only files, not subfolders. `FileInfo` objects have different properties.

Comment: yes the folder only contains files. I was wanting the name of the parent folder above the directory I am looking in.

Comment: For others, notice the use of the `@{ n = ... , e = { ... } }` technique described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.1#custom-expressions-in-common-pipeline-commands)